# Postgis ST_Intersects between two tables really (really really) slow

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to do a spatial join between two tables :

1. Table 1 : 397265 features (with gist index on geom field)
2. Table 2 : 73 features (with gist index on geom field)

Table 1 and 2 have the same SRID.

I did many tests and a spatial join between these tables take several days (after 5 days I've killed the query). I've tried to understand why it is so slow with explain analyze :

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT 
    table1.id,  table2.id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON ST_Intersects(
        ST_Buffer(table1.geom,0),
        ST_Buffer(table2.geom,0)
)
```

But for now I'm still waiting for the result as EXPLAIN ANALYZE really execute the query.

If I only do an EXPLAIN here is the result :

```
"Gather  (cost=1000.00..3820127.08 rows=9667 width=40)"
"  Workers Planned: 3"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3818111.26 rows=3118 width=40)"
"        Join Filter: ((st_buffer(table2.geom, '0'::double precision) && st_buffer(table1.geom, '0'::double precision)) AND _st_intersects(st_buffer(table2.geom, '0'::double precision), st_buffer(table1.geom, '0'::double precision)))"
"        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..21964.50 rows=128150 width=344)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..9.73 rows=73 width=714516)"
```

I've also updated my postgresql configuration file regarding my computer's configurarion :

```
shared_buffers = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 10485kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 7
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 7
```

Could you please tell me what it is so long ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spatial indexes are not used.

You can either drop the `buffer` thing (maybe fix your geometries first..)

```sql
INNER JOIN table2 ON ST_Intersects(table1.geom,table2.geom)
```

or you can create indexes on the buffered geometries

```sql
CREATE INDEX geom_idx ON table1 USING gist (ST_Buffer(table1.geom,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other comment suggests it's better to fix geometries. I guess you use buffer with zero distance to rebuild invalid geometries. So, what is better to do is

```
UPDATE table1 SET geom = st_buffer(geom,0);
UPDATE table2 SET geom = st_buffer(geom,0);
```

then reindex the table (rebuild its original gist index by geometry)

Also, depending on the geometries nature the index might be inefficient.
An index itself is basically a set of bounding boxes for every geometry (rectangles around polygonal or linear shapes), and it's much faster to determine which rectangles intersect first and then out of the pairs define exact geometry intersections. However, if you have too large polygons where most of rectangles are intersecting and/or too complex shapes it might slow down the join.

Also, you might have data that is heavy in terms of point density which also slows down the algorithms and can be removed without hurting the result much, especially if this data is not very spatially accurate. You can try to simplify your data, for example

```
ALTER table1 ADD COLUMN geom_simplified geom(<your geom type and srid>);
UPDATE table1 SET geom_simplified = st_snaptogrid(geom,<relevant rounding number depending on your srid and desired accuracy>);
```

check [this](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) out

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jgh for your answer, you've found the problem. The index was not used. 
I would have never found it as it was obvious for me that even with the buffer the index was used.

I've tried to clean the data but there are to many errors. So I've decided to use your solution (index on ST_Buffer())

My query takes now 14 hours. It is still a lot of time regarding the number of features in the table 2 but at least the query ends...

```
"Gather  (cost=1000.14..116847.28 rows=397265 width=8) (actual time=70.548..51214359.966 rows=415151 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 3"
"  Workers Launched: 3"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.14..76120.78 rows=128150 width=8) (actual time=1312.989..51210248.284 rows=103788 loops=4)"
"        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..21964.50 rows=128150 width=338) (actual time=0.009..3485.290 rows=99316 loops=4)"
"        ->  Index Scan using table2_idx_buffer on table2  (cost=0.14..0.41 rows=1 width=714516) (actual time=460.535..515.510 rows=0 loops=397265)"
"              Index Cond: (st_buffer(table1.geom, '0'::double precision) && st_buffer(geom, '0'::double precision))"
"              Filter: _st_intersects(st_buffer(table1.geom, '0'::double precision), st_buffer(geom, '0'::double precision))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 3"
"Planning time: 0.227 ms"
"Execution time: 51214434.490 ms"
```

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL 14 and PostGIS 3.3 on Ubuntu 22, I also faced the case of a very slow query mixing **ST_INTERSECTS** and  **INNER JOIN**  . In my case the **JOIN** was not even based on a spatial criteria. E.g. (this not the actual query but an example):

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.placename FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.fk=table2.pk
WHERE 
 ST_INTERSECTS(table2.geom, 
      ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
              'POLYGON((0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0,0 1))'
            ,4326)
            );
```

This query took about 80 seconds with **table1** having ca. 70 000 records and **table2** 30 000 records. Table2 has a spatial index and data in the geometry column are quite simple (points or very simple polygons).
The actual WKT geometry in the search statement was actually much bigger in area than in the example, but also used 4 points.
It seems to me that the same query was faster on earlier versions (it originally came from a project using PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS2.2 or PostGIS2.5).
I could overcome the difficulty by using a subquery in the WHERE part:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.placename FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.fk=table2.pk
WHERE table2.pk IN 
  (
    SELECT pk FROM table2 WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(table2.geom, 
    ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0,0 1))'
            ,4326))
  );
```

Although not optimal, because of the recursion on table2, this solution was much faster than the original query (ca 0.8 second while the first one took more than one minute). The internal strategy to call the spatial index has probably changed in the meantime.
A CTE could also be used to avoid the recursion :

```
WITH geo_filter AS (
SELECT pk, placename FROM table2 WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(table2.geom, 
   ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0,0 1))'
        ,4326))
)
SELECT table1.*, geo_filter.placename 
  FROM table1
    INNER JOIN geo_filter ON table1.fk= geo_filter.pk;
```